# How to build a new VS2008 WPF solution/project when you've lost the .sln and .csproj files?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008

I have an old VS2008 solution that had one project in it.

When I double-click on the .sln file it says that nothing can be found (**I had renamed some directories**).

So now what is the best way to take my main files (Window1.xaml, App.xaml, Properties folder, and about 10 other class files) and **recreate a solution and project for these main files again**?

## ANSWER:

Thanks Gerrie, you were right, manually was the only way:

- created new WPF solution
- recreated all folders
- right-clicked project, add existing items, changed to `*.*`, added all at once
- for each folder, add files as in above step

So in my case I was done in 5 minutes, but for larger solutions, one would hope there is an open-source tool or VS2008/VS2010 feature for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new solution and add everything.

In short: do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just open the .sln file in notepad and fix the paths to the project?

Answer (score 1):

Try File -> New Project -> Project from existing code

Or simply, create a new project having name of your choice in the same folder and then add the existing items into that project!

Comment: tried it, strangely no choice for WPF project only Console, Forms and Class Library.

Comment: Create a new WPF project; remove the default control/class etc and then add your existing files

Answer (score 0):

create new solution, new project, new classes, and copy & paste the content. 10 classes is not a hell of a job to do manually.

or

revert your changes in TFS